# Speed of file transfer NFS vs. Microsoft Network Share?

Tags: networking, operating-system, filesystems, nfs

I would like to know, if there are any performance differences using [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_(protocol)) instead of standard Microsoft Network Share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, yes there is. But I'd imagine it has lot to do with your specific workload and network set up. A [quick google](http://www.google.com/search?q=NFS+SMB+speed+comparison) might yield some useful information